# Python 2.7 mean, sum of the list

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to Python and having some assignment I am trying to get the sum and the averge of the list which is read from txt file.
The code I have come up with is:

```
def FileToList (filename):
    result = []
    try:
        f = open (filename,'r')
        for l in f.readlines ():
            result.append (l.strip())
        return result
    except IOError: 
        print ('File name not correct!')
        return []

infile = raw_input ('Please enter file.txt : ')
lines = FileToList (infile)
for list in lines:
    print (l)
```

It works and returns all values but I am struggling how to calculate them?

Comment: Additionally I would like to find the way to transfer the average to new file?

Comment: Can you provide a few sample lines of input and expected output?

Comment: You should really tell about the format of the file because as it stands the only problem seem to be parsing the file. The `sum` function can then be used to sum the list and together with `len` you can calculate the mean (the only thing you miss is a list of numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your input file contains floats, one number per line.
The following program ignores blank lines and takes care of the edge case when there are not numbers at all.

BTW I don't like your exception handling. It hides the actual reason. IMHO it's better to just not handle this exception. This will give the user better feedback about what exactly went wrong.

```
def calc_stats(filename):
    sum = 0.0
    cnt = 0
    for line in open(filename,"rt"):
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue # skip blank lines
        sum += float(line)
        cnt += 1
    return (sum, cnt)

infile = raw_input ('Please enter file.txt : ')
sum, cnt = calc_stats(infile)
if cnt == 0:
    print("sum=%f, count=%d" % (sum, cnt))
else:        
    print("sum=%f, count=%d, average=%f" % (sum, cnt, sum/cnt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each line contains the values separated (either by space or comma) you can simply convert the values to float, and then calculate the sum and mean:

```
for list in lines:    
    #convert to floats:
    flist = map(float, list.split())
    #calculate sum
    s = sum(flist)
    n = len(flist)        
    print "Sum: %f" % (s)
    if n>0:
       avg = s/n
       print "Average: %f" % (avg)
```

Note: if your data is split by commas you should use `list.split(',')`.